# How do I preserve previous data when deleting new columns or deleting exists table in Django models?

Tags: python, django

I am developing an ERP with groups of developers and we need to preserve customers data when deleting existing columns or table for Dajngo models and DB.

**For Example:**

I added a column named `columns1` and I gave the customer a release product of the System and then, but a week later I had to delete that new `column` but the customer have data stores in the `column1` column, here how can I preserve data or solve this situation.

**Another Example:**

I have a new column name `column2` with `unique` attr but here the customer have data, but I can not add new column with out allowed it to store the null data, but in this situation I do not want to allow the null data in column `column2` and ether I can't put `default` attr because it has `unique` attr.

How to solve these things in `Django`.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to add one Boolean field in the table field name delete if you want to delete the column don't delete it put delete field value to true. when you query add a filter with condition delete = false. i think this will work for 1st  condition

Comment: No, this is not what I meant .
I mean delete column not delete row of data.

Comment: you can create this column as a new table and when you write to this add employee id also . then connect to this table with foreign key. with default  null. then if you want to delete make it null in the foreign key field . is this works?

Answer (score 0):

Data migrations will help you solve these. You will have to write scripts in migrations to ensure the data is in the desired state before enforcing constraints e.g check `column2` to ensure the data is unique and proceed to add the `unique` constraint. Refer to this [tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/09/26/how-to-create-django-data-migrations.html) for more

Answer (score 0):

Usually in these case, you would need to backup your database to an sql file for example https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-backup-excerpt/5.7/en/mysqldump-sql-format.html.

After the backup you can change database structure however you want without worrying about the loss of data(because you saved in the backup sql). If you want to rollback the old version you can just apply the old DB(remember to backup your latest version of database too!). Or if you want to reapply deleted column just check the backup db data.